# Microsoft Teams returning error when file is uploaded in bot application using Team's attachment button

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We have an bot created on bot framework and enabled for Microsoft Teams channel. In the bot, the attachment functionality is enabled and user can send files to bot using Teams and it was working perfectly fine. But from past few week it stops working and uploading file in Team's bot chat is returning error. The attachment functionality is working when file is attached to user's chat and the problem is only coming on bot. It seems the issue is related to Teams client as the uploaded file disappears just after being upload. Please find the screenshot below with error message that appears when the file being uploaded automatically disappears in between. Request to please help with this issue.

[image: Teams Bot file upload message]

Comment: We are able to repro this on our side. We are investigating this internally.

Comment: I am also seeing this across multiple Teams tenants and different bot codebases today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI, Microsoft responded to my support ticket and fixed the issue for most tenants it seems.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/uploading-file-in-11-chat-with-bot-results-in-file/9449f0c0-1281-48f7-9535-b25ddd1b3753

If you're still affected you may need to reach out to them for further assistance

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes it is fixed for our bot also 

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue and found while looking into the teams logs that there is an access denied error when reading back the file. The file itself is uploaded:

"https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/apps/files/file?fileFullUrl=https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxx/Documents/Microsoft Teams-Chatdateien/test2.txt", status: 401, response: {"errorCode":"UnauthorizedAccess"}, errorCode: UnauthorizedAccess, requestId: undefined, correlationId: undefined, afdCorrelationId: Ref A: 6614FF68C2514756A3FC61C01FA13FC2 Ref B: AM3EDGE0708 Ref C: 2020-09-10T16:03:21Z

I already raised a ticket with Microsoft, but the team responded that the issue is most likely with my bot (although I did not change anything)